# What is the probability that a random sparse vector lies in a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a Finite Field. For $m\leq n$ a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{F}^n$ is $m$-sparse if $ \sum_i (v_i \neq 0) \leq m$, i.e. , the **hamming weight** is almost m. Let we call $S(n,m)$ the set of $m$-sparse vector of lenght $n$.

Let $V$ a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$, for simplicity let $V = Span(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})$ where $v_i$ are linear independent vector ( $|V|=n-1$ )

My question is an upperbound on

$$ \Pr[E(n,m)] := \Pr_{v\in S(n,m)}[ v \in V]$$

Such probability is very simple estimate in the case of $S(n,n)$. since

$$ \Pr[E(n,n)] = \frac{|F|^{n-1}}{|F|^n}$$

Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming finite fields? If not $|F|$ isn't very meaningful, and the probability is likely to be $0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I've totally missed to say that!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple indeed!

for any $v\in V$ we could write $v_n = \sum_i \alpha_i\times v_i$, since the space is of $n-1$ dimension.

We need to bound $P_{c\in S(n,m)}[c_n = \sum_i \alpha_i \times c_i]$.